# Using WKWebView/WKWebViewConfiguration on Xamarin.Mac with i386 architecture

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

My team and I are working in a Xamarin.Mac project with a SDK that need i386 architecture to being executed, and we have a federated login that use a WebView too.

We have a WebViewRenderer to catch the Navigating and Navigated events, and it works mostly fine in 64bits architecture, but when we changed the architecture by i386 the we view does not work more, it throws this error.

**Could not create an native instance of the type 'WebKit.WKWebViewConfiguration': the native class hasn't been loaded.**

This is the part of the code that raises the exception

```
public class ExtendedWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<ExtendedWebView, WKWebView>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ExtendedWebView> e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var wkWebView = new WKWebView(new CGRect(), new WKWebViewConfiguration());
            wkWebView.NavigationDelegate = new NavigationDelegate(this);

            SetNativeControl(wkWebView);

            SetSource();
```